# How do I exclude certain latex tags in OpenDetex?

Tags: latex, detex, opendetex

I am trying to spellcheck a LaTeX document (using Word), and use OpenDetex to convert it to plain text. The command line with default parameters:

```
$ detex foo.tex > foo.txt
```

Problem: some garbage, especially bibliography ids from `\citep{}` and `\citet{}` commands stay in the text.

How can I exclude these specific tags?

The `-c` option only excludes `\cite`, but not `\citep` and `\citet`.

I tried using the `-e` option like:

```
$ detex -e citep foo.tex > foo.txt
```

to no avail.

The documentation is a bit vague on that:

```
detex [-e environment-list] [-c] [-l] [-n] [-s] [-t] [-w] [file[.tex] ]
...
-e  <env-list> list of LaTeX environments to ignore\n  
...
```

Any ideas how to make it work?

Comment: Probably not the answer you're looking for but you could try using Pandoc instead to do the conversion.

Comment: An alternative would be to use a [LaTeX aware spell checker or editor](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15/spell-checking-latex-documents).

Answer (score 0):

`\citep` and `\citet` are not LaTeX environments, they are commands, and as such the `-e` flag of `detex` has no effect on it. The flag `-e` is only for environments.

The new version of `detex` 2.8.2 that you can obtain [here.](https://github.com/pkubowicz/opendetex)

as long as the commands (\citep and \citet) do not start at the first character in a line -- that is a bug and will be fixed.